# django Pass Search word from post field to URL

Tags: django

Good day,

I need to send a string from an input field to a URL.
my search engine is in Employees. views

and it looks something like this.

```
def search_in_employees(request, search):
    print(search)
    return render(request, "employees/employee_list.html")
```

it's pretty simple.
my URL looks like this.

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from .import views


app_name = 'employees'

urlpatterns = [
    path('create/', views.EmployeesCreateView.as_view(), name='create'),
    path('list/', views.EmployeesListView.as_view(), name='list'),
    path('update/<pk>/', views.EmployeesUpdateView.as_view(), name='update'),
    path('delete/<pk>/', views.EmployeesDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete'),
    path('update_db', views.UpdateDataBase.as_view(), name='update_db'),
    path('search/<search>', views.search_in_employees, name='search'),
]
```

and the form in the template looks like this.

```
        <form action="{% url 'employees:search' search %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search..." aria-label="Search">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" id="button-addon2">
          </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

there is something wrong with the code but I just can find what is it. the error message it's this.
[image]

thank you in advance for any help.
best

[image]

Comment: You need to pass a search argument into `"{% url 'employees:search' [...] %}"`. Can you show your view which this `navigation.html` template originates from. Please edit question to reflect this addition.

Comment: Thank you Lewis i Tried that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Couldn't find an answer for this inside Django or python, I used js for this. I wrote:

```
        <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search_input" name="search" placeholder="Search..." aria-label="Search">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"  type="submit" id="search_summit">
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var search_summit = document.getElementById("search_summit")
        search_summit.addEventListener('click', function (){
            var searchValue = document.getElementById("search_input").value;
            if(searchValue.length >= 1){
            window.location.href = '/employees/search/'+ searchValue;
            };
        });
    </script>
```

i had to remove the form tag and just use an addEvenListener for the click and redirect the input to the employee view.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do two things to make this work.

1. Make the "search" attribute in your method optional and
2. add a second URLs entry for the URL without a search param that you could use in your form's action.

   path('search/', views.search_in_employees, name='search'),
   path('search', views.form_employees, name='search-form'),

   ```
    <form action="{% url 'employees:search-form' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
           <div class="input-group">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search..." aria-label="Search">
           <div class="input-group-append">
               <input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" id="button-addon2">
           </div>
           </div>
    </form>
   ```